# How to calculate the gcd of (3^{100!}-1,116)?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have to find out the result of $$(3^{100!}-1,116)$$

This is an exercise after the chapter of integer factorization and now I need help.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate that expression or find its GCD?

Comment: I have to find the gcd of the expression

Answer (score 3):

$116
=4\cdot 29
$.

$3^{100!}-1
=9^{100!/2}-1
=(9-1)\sum_{k=0}^{100!/2-1} 9^k
=8\sum_{k=0}^{100!/2-1} 9^k
$
so the gcd is either
$4$ or $4\cdot 29$.

Since
$a^{29} \equiv a
\bmod 29$,
$\bmod 29$
we have
$3^{100!}
\equiv 3^{100! \bmod 28}
\equiv 3^0
\equiv 1
$
since
$28 | 100!$.

Therefore
$3^{100!}
\equiv 1 \bmod 29
$
so the gcd is 116.

Comment: Thank you very much.  : )